# Online Ticketing Purchase Timer

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Can someone please guide me as to what is the best way to have the time restriction timer in one of my online application written in Classic ASP with MsAccess database.

Simple process..Once the user shops, the system redirects the user to enter the billing & shipping information where-in this timer is shown and valid for 10 minutes.

Initially I captured the server side time and added 10 minutes using Classic ASP's DateAdd function "DATEADD("n",10, TIME())" and then used JavaScript to match the current time with the expiry time. But since site can be accessed from any part of the world, so taking server time is not helpful as Javascript matching is taking local PC time, so it will never match.

Secondly, when the user refreshes the page, the 10 minute timer will restart.

Appreciate your help. It can be through Javascript or Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page1, do this

```
session("shopping_time") = now
```

In the subsequent pages

do this,

```
session("current_time" ) = now
time_elapsed = datediff("n",session("current_time" ),session("shopping_time"))
if ( time_elapsed > 10 ) then
    //do something
end if
```

Comment: Thanks John the idea of storing the expiry time in session is good. I just need to use JavaScript to decrement the remaining time. Excellent. Thanks for your help.